# DRCSim + Precise + Hydro

Tags: drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'd like to use Atlas in Gazebo with ROS Hydro and Ubuntu 12.04. I have `gazebo-current` 2.2.1-1 installed from debian and Hydro installed from debian. Next I tried to install DRCSim from source loosely following the [Groovy instructions](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/Install#Compiling_from_source) by making a new catkin workspace and cloning

> hg clone https://bitbucket.org/osrf/osrf-common

> hg clone https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sandia-hand

> hg clone https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim

When I compile, I get the error:

> /home/dave/ros/ws_atlas/src/drcsim/drcsim_gazebo_ros_plugins/src/IRobotHandPlugin.cpp: In member function ‘void IRobotHandPlugin::UpdatePIDControl(double)’:
> /home/dave/ros/ws_atlas/src/drcsim/drcsim_gazebo_ros_plugins/src/IRobotHandPlugin.cpp:284:32: error: ***‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetUpperLimit’***
> /home/dave/ros/ws_atlas/src/drcsim/drcsim_gazebo_ros_plugins/src/IRobotHandPlugin.cpp: In member function ‘void IRobotHandPlugin::SetJointSpringDamper()’:
> /home/dave/ros/ws_atlas/src/drcsim/drcsim_gazebo_ros_plugins/src/IRobotHandPlugin.cpp:649:15: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetStiffnessDamping’
> /home/dave/ros/ws_atlas/src/drcsim/drcsim_gazebo_ros_plugins/src/IRobotHandPlugin.cpp:666:15: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetStiffnessDamping’
> /home/dave/ros/ws_atlas/src/drcsim/drcsim_gazebo_ros_plugins/src/IRobotHandPlugin.cpp:679:12: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetStiffnessDamping’
> /home/dave/ros/ws_atlas/src/drcsim/drcsim_gazebo_ros_plugins/src/IRobotHandPlugin.cpp:693:12: error: ‘class gazebo::physics::Joint’ has no member named ‘SetStiffnessDamping’
> make[2]: ** [drcsim/drcsim_gazebo_ros_plugins/CMakeFiles/IRobotHandPlugin.dir/src/IRobotHandPlugin.cpp.o] Error 1
> make[1]: ** [drcsim/drcsim_gazebo_ros_plugins/CMakeFiles/IRobotHandPlugin.dir/all] Error 2

It seems its looking for a different version of Gazebo?

Thanks!

---

Update:

I'm now on default branch for Gazebo and am compiling from source. While running `make` I get:

`/home/dave/ros/ws_gazebo/gazebo/interfaces/player/player.h:22:38: fatal error: libplayercore/playercore.h: No such file or directory`

I have `libplayercore3.0-dev` installed, not sure whats going on.

---

Update:

There does not appear to be a `-I/usr/include/player3.0` when I compile. I do have the file:

> /usr/include/player-3.0/libplayercore/playercore.h

The compile flags are:

```
cd /home/dave/ros/ws_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/gui && /usr/bin/c++   -Dgazebo_gui_EXPORTS -DLIBBULLET_VERSION=0.0 -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -g -O2 -mssse3 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -msse -msse2  -Wall -Wextra -Wno-long-long
```

-Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-value -Wno-unused-value -Wfloat-equal -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wswitch-default -Wmissing-include-dirs -pedantic  -g -O2 -mssse3 -msse3 -mfpmath=sse -msse -msse2  -fPIC
-I/home/dave/ros/ws_gazebo/gazebo/test/gtest/include -I/home/dave/ros/ws_gazebo/gazebo -I/home/dave/ros/ws_gazebo/gazebo/build -I/home/dave/ros/ws_gazebo/gazebo/deps -isystem /usr/include/OGRE/RTShaderSystem -isystem /usr/include/OGRE
-isystem /usr/include/OGRE/Terrain -isystem /usr/include/OGRE/Paging -isystem /usr/include/sdformat-1.4 -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore    -fPIC -o
CMakeFiles/gazebo_gui.dir/moc_JointControlWidget.cxx.o -c /home/dave/ros/ws_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/gui/moc_JointControlWidget.cxx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5269/drcsim-+-precise-+-hydro/) by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 369 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The current drcsim from default needs gazebo 3.0 version (current default branch). Otherwise you will get this error about SetUpperLimit.

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2014-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2014-01-21**:
Ok, I'm now on default branch for Gazebo and am compiling from source. While running `make` I get:

`/home/dave/ros/ws_gazebo/gazebo/interfaces/player/player.h:22:38: fatal error: libplayercore/playercore.h: No such file or directory`
I have `libplayercore3.0-dev` installed

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-01-21**:
You have two options: check that libplayercore/playercore.h is present in your system under /usr/include. If so, compile with VERBOSE=1 and check that there is a -I/usr/include/player3.0 as compiler parameter. In both are right, it should compile. The other option is to get rid of all the player support in gazebo (are you planning on using it?) just uninstall it: sudo apt-get remove libplayer*

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2014-01-21**:
`sudo apt-get remove libplayer*` fixed the problem, though I added more details in the question, above, and I'd be interested to know why it didn't work with it installed. Perhaps this is a bug that should be worked out in the new Gazebo 3.0?

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-01-21**:
Given your details, it could be a bug in the player support. Could you please file a bug in the gazebo bug tracker and assign it to me? Thanks for the complete report Dave.

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2014-01-23**:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1018/compiling-gazebo-30-without-player-support